# HPOM Java GUI, multiple users connecting to different servers from Citrix sessions on the same server possible?

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, filesystems, citrix

I have an app (HPOM Java GUI) running on a 2008 R2 Xenapp 6 box that employs client certificates for encrypting connections to the HPOM server.

I have 2 different sets of users who will use this app to connect to 2 different HPOM servers.

The client certificate store is not held in user profile folders, it goes under ProgramData, so out of the box, both sets of users will always see the same files in this certificate store.

Ideally, I would like 2 users from the different groups to be logged into the same Citrix box simultaneously, and be able to see their own client certificate files, but in the same folder.

(The certificate store doesn't seem to be configurable to handle 2 servers at once)

So effectively, users from the first group will see the filesystem differently from users in the second group.

Alternatively, if there is a way to have different users point to different cert stores in the HPOM Java GUI configuration, then that would be even better, but I've not found a way to do this either.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say I've looked at mklink to create a link from the cert store into the users profile folder, but this just means that when this is done for the first user, all other users will se e this. This doesn't seem to allow 2 users to see different things.

Comment: I almost changed it for you, but I think you should alter your title to something like "HPOM Server, how to have 2 sets of users use different certificates" or similar.  The issue at hand isn't really about Windows 2008.

Comment: I see your point; what I was asking was a way to achieve my end goal. There may be other ways, so I have changed it to actually state my goal, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it was more of an XY problem, but looks much better now.